# Find the total number of students

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a parent class called StudentBody and a child class called MathStudentBody. My question is how can i explained the child class so as to find the total number of students in the class? I guess we have to find out the total number of objects created ? Can anyone point me to the right direction

```
class StudentBody:

    count = 0
    def __init__(self, name,gender,year,gpa):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.year = year
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.count+= 1

    def IsFreshman(self):
        print "I am the StudentBody method"
        if self.year == 1:
            return True
        else :
            return False

    def countTotal(self):
        return self.count

class MathStudentBody(StudentBody):

    def __init__(self,name,gender,year,gpa,mathSATScore):
        #super(MathStudentBody,self).__init__(name,gender,year,gpa)
        StudentBody.__init__(self,name,gender,year,gpa)
        self.MathSATScore = mathSATScore

    def IsFreshman(self):
        print "I am the MathStudentBody method"


    def CombinedSATandGPA(self):
        return self.gpa*100 + self.MathSATScore

    def NumberOfStudents(self):
        return
```

Comment: In your code you call `self.count += 1`, doesn't this fail?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: no, that will just access `StudentBody.count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like this (stripped down your code to the bare minimum...)

```
class StudentBody:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        StudentBody.count+= 1

class MathStudentBody(StudentBody):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                        # python 3
        # super(MathStudentBody, self).__init__() # python 2
        MathStudentBody.count+= 1

s = StudentBody()
ms = MathStudentBody()

print(StudentBody.count)  # 2
print(MathStudentBody.count) # 1
```

note that i changed the access to the class variable to `StudentBody.count` (from `self.count` which works if you read only. but as soon as you assign something to `self.count` the change will only affect the instance `self` and not the class). and calling `super().__init__()` in `MathStudentBody` will increase `StudentBody.count` as well.

([`Body.count`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_Count)... chuckle!)